# Can I share a single Angular project to be used for Web & Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have Angular 5 project that is working fine and compiled version (html,css,js) of it is deployed on a webserver and is used by users. This project uses @angular/material2, and angularfire5.

I am interested in creating mobile apps, and learned that Ionic uses Angular framework to create mobile apps.

When I actually checked out the examples, it seems that Ionic uses Angular components directly, which made me think that I could just re-use existing Angular components that I have built for the web app. I was thinking of just creating new Ionic view files and integrating it with existing angular components that I have.

I was wondering if there is a good guidelines to follow or even possible to have a setup where single project directory can be used for regular Angular webapp & Ionic app.

The goal that I am trying to achieve here is that I am trying to avoid a situation where I have to maintain web version of the angular component and mobile (ionic) version of the angular component separately for every single component that I have.

Is there an elegant way to do solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could have a "shared" source control project which includes some common directives,pipies and components that you pull in to your web and mobile projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any `Angular AOT` compatible components with `Ionic 3.x` project. But the problem you'll have here is the `navigation` system.It is so different on `Ionic 3` project.

Here you can read more about [**Ionic navigation system**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

**Note:** If you have any other questions feel free to ask.